# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.admin' in pythonanywhere

Tags: django, pythonanywhere, django-deployment, django-dev-server

hi i know this is repetitive question but i checked everywhere and i checkd my urls and import stuffs but it does not fix i don't know which file path is incorrect
i clone my project from github and my project in localhost works all right
but in [pythonanywhere.com](http://pythonanywhere.com) i have this error here is my `wsgi.py` code:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/gazegan/blood-donor/bblood/'
if path not in sys.path:
sys.path.append(path)


os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'bblood.settings'
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and this is the full error:

```
Error running WSGI application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.admin'
File "/var/www/gazegan_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 57, in <module>
application = get_wsgi_application()

File "/home/gazegan/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in
django.setup(set_prefix=False)
File "/home/gazegan/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/gazegan/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/home/gazegan/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/apps/config.py", line 136, in create
import_module(entry)
```

please help me :(

Comment: What did you set as the path to the source code and working directory on python anywhere web configuration page?

Comment: my project name is `bblood` this is my source code `/home/gazegan/blood-donor/bblood`
for example manage.py file is stored in `/home/gazegan/blood-donor/bblood/manage.py`. and my working directory is `home/gazegan/`

Comment: by the way i configurate the admin static files like what in tutorial said. in static part of web configuration i add this `/home/gazegan/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin` and `/static/admin/` as url mybe that is the problem :(

Comment: It appears that you can import django, but not django.contrib.admin, so that makes me think that your installation of django is broken in some way. Try deleting and rebuilding your virtualenv.

Comment: Yeeesss, You were right my problem solved! thank you very much @Glenn